# BrowserSync wont load proxy from webpack

Tags: node.js, laravel, proxy, browser-sync

Im having issue related to BrowserSync Proxy using Laravel recently,
No idea how because everything was working before.

here is my webpack.mix.js

```
 mix.browserSync({
Proxy: 'localhost:8000'});
```

and each time i run

```
npm run watch
```

it run the proxy to default configuration which is http://app.test instead of localhost:8000

```
   1 WARNING in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack compiled with 1 warning
[Browsersync] Proxying: http://app.test
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3002
    External: http://192.168.0.149:3002
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3003
 UI External: http://localhost:3003
```

Ive tried to reinstall browserSync
And change webpack proxy to various addresses 127.0.0.1 but it keeps having same issue
is there another way i could try to change the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by running this instead

```
>browser-sync start --proxy localhost:8000
```

Still couldnt figure it out why my webpack.mix.js was ignored.